# paytm payment gateway working fine but not redirecting to app after payment successs?

Tags: android, google-play, payment-gateway, payumoney, paytm

```
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp";
```

this is my call back url 
payment is working fine but i can't get back to activity after paymentsuccess  see the image below
money got  detucted from staging account and updated in dashboard 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/irNHz.png

Comment: Is your issue resolved ??

Comment: I am having same issue in my app

Comment: I am facing same issue in my app. please help me

Answer (score 0):

you have to contact paytm tech support and they will ask your merchant id. after they updated it will work fine .
any help?